# Update input in real-time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a script for percentage calculation on my e-commerce, but I have a problem.

I want price update in real time as I write the percentage in the field.

So I made this:

```
<input type="text" name="cost" onchange="disc()">

<input type="text" name="discount" id="prized" onchange="updateInput()">

<input type="text" name="price" value="">

<script>
function updateInput(){

  var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;
  var cost = document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value;
  document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = cost - (cost * (discount / 100)); 

}

function disc(){

    if($("#prized").val().length > 1) {

        var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;
        var cost = document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value;
        document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = cost - (cost * (discount / 100));

    }
}
<script>
```

But it does not work as I would like...

It does not update in real time, for "onchange".

So I did some research, and I found an interesting function: `.keydown()`

I have no idea how to use it in my script.

Someone can help me reach my goal?

Comment: Use onkeyup, not only onchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `onchange` by `oninput` should give you de behaviour you are looking for, the following snippet works for me:

```js
function updateInput() {
  var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;
  var cost = document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value;
  document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = cost - (cost * (discount / 100)); 
}

function disc() {
 console.log(document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value);

 if($("#prized").val().length > 1) {

  var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;
  var cost = document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value;
  document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = cost - (cost * (discount / 100));
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="cost" oninput="disc()"> <br><br>

<input type="text" name="discount" id="prized" oninput="updateInput()">

<input type="text" name="price" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things: There's no need to use getElementBy* when using jQuery, there's no need to write the same function twice.

On `input` (rather than change or keyup) of both fields, run the function

```
$(function(){
    $('#prized, #cost').on('input', function(){
    var discount = $('#prized').val();
    var cost = $('#cost').val();
    var price = cost - (cost * (discount / 100));
    $('#price').val(price);
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/popnoodles/npgvmLkc/2/

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 errors here:

First, you are not converting the values of the input fields to numbers; use parseInt() for this.

Second, declare your number inputs as such using ´type="number"´. This increases usability, as you will see.

Answer to your question:
If you use parseInt() in updateInput() and use `onkeyup="updateInput"` (or even better `onkeypress="updateInput()"` this should work. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/da5d92bk/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("input[name='discount']").bind('input propertychange', function() {
    //do your update here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use keyup listener like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var copyField = $('#copyvalue');  //field where you want to copy

$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() != '') {
       copyField.val($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

$('#idofelement').keydown(function() {
...
});

Comment: This doesn't answer the question